# URL Rewrite Module Questions / Problems

Tags: url, iis, module, url-rewriting

I am tasked with creating some rewrite rules for a .Net MVC site in IIS 7.5.  I installed the Url Rewrite Module, and configured a couple of very simple rules without success.

So my first question is, in which order does IIS process the incoming url?
Is it Incomming URL --> URL Rewrite --> rewrite the Url --> .Net MVC Routing Manager gets the updated URL?

If not then in which order does it process it and how can I get the URL Rewrite to process the URL first?

There is a checkbox that says "Log rewritten URL", does this log to the IIS log or is this for something else?

Here is the rewrite inbound rule I created:

```
Pattern: (.*)/fin/(.*)
Rewrite URL: {R:1}/fi/{R:2}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update: 4/5/2012**
I still can't get it to work on the system.  I tried hitting it via the Localhost to eliminate proxy's and load balances and it still won't work.  I installed it to another machine, and it works like a champ.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

** Update: 4/6/2012**
I still haven't tracked down the problem, but I wonder if my web.config for my MVC app is causing any problems.  Does it appear that these statements in the web.config could be causing this?:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: I don't know all the answers so just commenting. But yes, that checkbox does indeed put "stuff" into the IIS Log.

Comment: thanks, some clarification is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

April 11, 2012 Update

URL Rewrite Module is actually installed correctly.  Did some very basic tests and they worked.  Discovered that my regular expression for my rule was incorrect (had an extra slash) and I needed to do an IISReset.  If anybody else finds this post, make sure your redirect rules are correct, and do a very simple basic test to verify its working.

Answer (score 0):

Ray,

You're right about the rewrite process steps. IIS will rewrite the URL first before passing the request on to the appropriate asp.net app.

Take care in using IIS rewrite, though, with routing, as they can contend with each other.
 Especially if IIS rewrites a URL in a way you didn't expect. To me, cases like this prove Jeff Atwood was right when he blogged:

[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Generally I'll err on the side of using routing over IIS rewrite, and will only use IIS rewrite to enforce general rules, like establishing a canonical domain (www vs no www), forcing lower case urls or enforcing the trailing slash on a URL.

Your problem seems more specific than that. I would exhaust all of my options with routing before taking a shotgun to the problem (like URL rewrite).